# Knockout virtual elements not working with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

If you run this Fiddle in Chrome, the select box is correctly filled with options A, B, and C.  However, if you run it with Internet Explorer (version 8 or 9), it does not work.  How can I fix this fiddle to make it work with Internet Explorer, but still use virtual elements?

http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/2tUmP/

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/html" id="template">
    <select id="type" name="type">
        <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
        <!-- ko foreach: types -->
        <option data-bind="text: $data.desc, attr: { value: $data.id }"></option>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </select>
</script>
<div id="placeholder" data-bind="template: { name: 'template' }"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function Model(){
    var self = this;
    self.types = ko.observable([]);
}
var model = new Model();
model.types().push({id: 0, desc:'A'});
model.types().push({id: 1, desc:'B'});
model.types().push({id: 2, desc:'C'});

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably a limitation of Internet Explorer.

Instead of a virtual element, use the `options` binding to populate a `<select>` element:

```
<select id="type" name="type"
    data-bind="options: types, optionsText: 'desc', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: '-- Choose --'">
</select>
```

Documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: It should be noted that the limitation is only regarding virtual bindings within a `<select>` element. They work fine elsewhere. Also the issue is no longer present in IE10,11.