# knockout.js MVVM if condition is not working in IE8

Tags: knockout.js

My code is below one. Ko if condition is not working in IE9 & IE8.

```
<select id="ProductsList" data-bind="foreach: controlConfig, value: $root.Name">
    <!--ko if:$data.Type=='List_Item-Instruction'-->
         <option data-bind="text: $data.DescriptionText"></option>
    <!--/ko-->
    <!--ko if:$data.Type=='List_Item-Category' || $data.Type=='List_Item'-->
         <option data-bind="text: $data.Name"></option>
    <!--/ko-->
</select>
```

Any help?

Comment: You're missing angle bracket `>` on one of your ending `if` statement. Try correcting and that see if that works.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524003/knockout-virtual-elements-not-working-with-internet-explorer. It turns out there is a bug with `select` and virtual elements in IE. Follow @QBM5's suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of better ways to do this.

```
<select id="ProductsList" data-bind="foreach: controlConfig, value: $root.Name">
    <option data-bind="text: ($data.Type == "List_Item-Instruction") ? $data.DescriptiveText : $data.Name"></option>
</select>
```

or, depending on your object structure, check if DescriptiveText is null or not

```
 <select id="ProductsList" data-bind="foreach: controlConfig, value: $root.Name">
    <option data-bind="text: !!$data.DescriptiveText() ||  $data.Name()"></option>
</select>
```

You may also have to unwrap the property if it is an observable like so.

```
<option data-bind="text: ($data.Type() == "List_Item-Instruction") ? $data.DescriptiveText() : $data.Name()"></option>
```

Comment: Or, add a `computed` (something like `displayName`) to your view model to do this logic for you. That way the html bindings to this are much more succinct :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="ProductsList" data-bind="foreach: controlConfig, value: $root.Name">
    <!--ko if:$data.Type=='List_Item-Instruction'-->
         <option data-bind="text: $data.DescriptionText"></option>
    <!--/ko-->
    <!--ko if:$data.Type=='List_Item-Category' || $data.Type=='List_Item'-->
         <option data-bind="text: $data.Name"></option>
    <!--/ko-->
</select>
```

The reason why this doesn't work in IE8 is because IE* removes comments from select elements. If you inspect the html in IE8 you'll notice that the knockout comments are gone :(. QBM5 has offered some solutions to this issue. I'd recommend using the [select binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html). You also need to be aware if you are using a version before 2.3 you'll have have issues with multiple bindings on a select binding. You can find more information about that at ryan niemeyer's [blog](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/06/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-3-all-bindings.html).