# Alternative method to knockout virtual binding

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following code that works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, and IE10, but it doesn't work in IE9. Specifically, IE9 seems to not allow virtual binding within a select element. I have been trying to find an alternative way of doing what I'm currently doing (one list contains all elements with property "IsSelected" equal to false, and the other list has all elements with property "IsSelected" equal to true) but can't seem to find the right way for compatibility among all browsers.

```
<select data-bind="foreach:Credentials" multiple="multiple" id="UnselectedCredentialsList" name="UnselectedCredentialsList" size="22">
    <!-- ko 'if': !IsSelected() -->
    <option data-bind="text:Name,value:Id" class="qloptions"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>

<select data-bind="foreach:Credentials" multiple="multiple" id="SelectedCredentialsList" name="SelectedCredentialsList">
    <!-- ko 'if': IsSelected() -->
    <option data-bind="text:Name,value:Id" class=" qloptions"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

Comment: How this question is different than your previous one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174438/ko-comment-tags-not-working-in-ie9

Comment: Can't you add two computed observable to your view model one that is your `Credentials` filtered by `IsSelected() == true` and the other `false`?

Answer (score 1):

As the linked question in your now deleted previous question said:

[Knockout virtual elements not working with Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524003/knockout-virtual-elements-not-working-with-internet-explorer)

This is a known problem with virtual elements in select tags for `<IE 10`

One way to work around this would be to have `computed` properties that you can bind each `select` to. For example, inside your VM:

```
var self = this;
self.selectedCredentials = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Credentials(), function(item) {
        return item.IsSelected();
    });
}
```

And then you can bind that:

```
<select data-bind="options:selectedCredentials, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id'"
    multiple="multiple" id="UnselectedCredentialsList" 
    name="UnselectedCredentialsList" size="22">
```

And obviously you can do the same for the unselected items.

Comment: When you say that I'd do the same for the unselected items do you mean I would create a new computed array as well? Or I would just create another select group that would correspond to the unselected items?

Comment: @John: Yes, create another computed but with the filter `!item.IsSelected()`. If you wanted to get fancy you could probably work out how to do it with a single computed looping through the collection only once, but unless the collection is huge, it's probably not worth the effort.